# jQuery's $(selector).position().left Sometimes Fails in Firefox, Chrome Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I have a content slideshow:

slide container 
|--> wrapper 
|------> slide1, slide2, etc.

that works as simple as calculating wrapper's position X and slide's position X to determine where to slide the wrapper for the next/previous slide to show up within container's viewport. It's pretty straight forward.

For Firefox and Chrome I am using CSS3 transform and transition-duration to animate the slides. Everything works perfect. Almost.

The problem is only when I click next button very fast. I am using jQuery's

```
$(selector).position().left
```

to read the slide's position X (left) and position becomes **0** (instead of expected, say, 300px). I do have a flag isAnimating to prevent users from going too fast but that does not help either. It does prevent from scrolling content too fast but position left may still be **0** as if something else is causing it to fail to determine.

I did a brief search and discovered that if it was image being loaded, some browsers would fail to determine its position until loading is over. However, each slide has an image but inside of it. The slide's CSS seems to have all widths and margins set fine.

The question is why may this be happening based on the scenario I described and possibly what can be improved to determine position X at all times for Firefox, Chrome browsers?

Comment: Share an example that reproduces the error and you'll get a much faster and more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided that if **offsetLeft** is not reliable for me at all times, I could use width of an element and its index position within container to figure out position X

```
var newWrapperPos = undefined;
$(lotWrapper).children('div').each(function(index){
        if($(this).attr("id") === "slot"+id){
            var width = $(this).width();
            newWrapperPos = index * width;
            return false;
        }
    }); 
//now I can shift wrapper to position = newWrapperPos
```

Sorry I couldn't share the code - it is a bit time consuming to rip off all pieces of functionality involved. But if somebody has a better answer, let me know. For now this works fine for me.